# Listing primary keys in Fox Pro with the OLE DB Provider?

Tags: database, primary-key, foxpro, visual-foxpro

How does one list the primary keys of a table in Fox Pro with the OLE DB Provider?

Using C# and switching my build to x86 instead of x64 I was able to use oledb provider for Fox Pro to display some information about the table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace obtainFoxSchema
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=X:\\FREETABLES\\DATA;"
            );
            connection.Open();
            DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema(
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables
            );

            foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowTables in tables.Rows)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(rowTables["table_name"].ToString());
                DataTable columns = connection.GetSchema(
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns,
                    new String[] { null, null, rowTables["table_name"].ToString(), null }
                );
                foreach (System.Data.DataRow rowColumns in columns.Rows)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(
                        rowTables["table_name"].ToString() + "." +
                        rowColumns["column_name"].ToString() + " = " +
                        rowColumns["data_type"].ToString()
                    );
                }
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine("stop");
        }
    }
}
```

But I really don't know where to look in the objects returned to find the primary keys or the foreign keys between tables.

Any ideas where that kind of thing might be?

And yes I found the code for this in another question, but I built the connection string myself using Excel 2007's Get External Data.

Comment: I don't have FoxPro to work with...I do have SQL Server however...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your post on Twitter. I am answering this question as a VFP developer with very little experience in Visual Studio and C#.

Not sure if you need things programmatically or just need to get the details. Have you tried to add the database to the Server Explorer? According to the Visual FoxPro Help File...

To connect to a Visual FoxPro database or table through the Visual FoxPro OLE DB Provider
Open Visual Studio.

1. From the View menu, select Server Explorer.
2. In the Server Explorer pane, right-click Data Connections, and click Add Connection
3. In the Data Link Properties dialog box, click the Provider tab.
4. Select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro.
5. The Connection tab in the Data Link Properties dialog box appears.

If this is not helpful, there is a DDEX provider, but it might only work with a specific version of Visual Studio.

http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sedna&referringTitle=Home#DDEX

If you are using the Entity Framework, there is a provider:

http://vfpefprovider.codeplex.com/

Rick

Comment: Sounds like it's worth a shot!  Thank you!

Comment: Well I'm using VS 2008, so I guess it's a little different from your directions, but it appears to have listed the tables at least.  (though they don't appear to have primary keys which astounds me)  But I will have to try your other two suggestions.  VS 2008 seems to be really fast at listing the data however.

Comment: Older applications built on FoxPro for DOS and FoxPro for Windows might be using "free tables", which are not contained in a database container (DBC). Even VFP applications can use free tables. These files would not have primary or candidate keys because they are only available in DBCs.

Comment: You people do realize its not possible to make a 64-bit process support Visual Fox Pro right? You really should use a database backend that support 64-bit if you plan on using a 64-bit operating system. Suggesting a VFP solution should be criminal.  It seems silly to go backward when there isn't a valid reason to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound It's a legacy system that I'm working on.  They are moving away from it, but in the mean time this is what they use.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the Primary Keys and Foreign Keys from the connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable method.

Example:

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=vfpoledb;data source=c:\NorthwindData\Northwind.dbc")) {
    connection.Open();
    DataTable primaryKeys = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys, null);
    DataTable foreignKeys = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys, null);
}
```

However, the Primary Keys DataTable doesn't let you know if a Primary Key is an AutoInc.  If you are interested in getting VFP specific schema information then you might want to try using [VfpClient](http://vfpclient.codeplex.com/) instead of the OleDb classes.

VfpClient Example:

```
using(var connection = new VfpConnection(@"c:\NorthwindData\Northwind.dbc")) {
    connection.Open();
    DataTable primaryKeys = connection.GetSchema(VfpConnection.SchemaNames.PrimaryKeys);
    DataTable foreignKeys = connection.GetSchema(VfpConnection.SchemaNames.ForeignKeys);
}
```

btw... the VfpClient includes a DDEX Provider that works with VS2010 and VS2012.